# Code block containing asterisks displaying in italics

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Why is "DRSI" displaying in italics in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64111075/256196)?

I expect markdown to be disabled in code blocks, because some code happens to conform to certain markdown patterns.

Interestingly, on SO the *preview* does **not** display is italics, but *rendered* version does.
Here, on the other hand it renders OK.

Here's a copy of the code block:

```
FOR PURPOSES.*?DRSI.*?\.
```

Comment: Because highlight.js marked the text as *emphasis*. This often happens when highlight.js has to guess at the source language.

Comment: Fixed by setting the code block language to `none`

Comment: Is it a bug? It doesn't *really* matter *that* much since the code can still be correctly highlighted, copied and pasted.

Comment: The preview will also show the issue of you let syntax highlighting catch up. It is not being parsed as markdown, it’s parsed as code but the highlighter has support for markdown-like constructs when in auto-mode.

Comment: So we except our users to do this? Hmmm. I'm leaving this open to see what kind of voting it attracts. Happy for it to be nuked too.  Just reporting it really.

Comment: Wow. That's quite a rendering lag. About 5+ seconds. Cool.

Comment: It amazes me that you haven't noticed the preview render lag before this point ^^", it's been there for... Quite some time

Comment: @Nick Be amazed. I've never noticed it. I don't look at preview that often - mainly just to the code indentation right.

Comment: If you're annoyed at the 5-second delay before syntax highlighting kicks in like I was, you can use [my userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Instant-Syntax-Highlighting)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the syntax highlighter trying to guess at a language for the regex. highlight.js has 3 language definitions that use an *emphasis* class, rendered as italic text.

Since there is very little text and there is no regex language definition for highlight.js, the highlighter ended up picking the *markdown* language definition and marked the part between asterisks with the *emphasis* class. Highlight.js uses a reasonably smart algorithm to pick languages but because the text is so short it had very little to work with.

I’ve forced the issue by disabling highlighting for that code block by setting the language to `none`, like this:

````
```none
<lines incorrectly highlighted>
```
````

Note that the issue definitely is visible in the editor preview too, you just need to make sure you let the highlighter kick in (there is a few second delay after you stop editing).

Comment: Should perhaps the site be updated to automatically supply or guess `none` when no explicit language tag is present? I'm getting this on a [tag:regex] question (probably deleted by the time you read this, but [here.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134963/i-am-getting-a-problem-while-writing-regex-for-manually-enter-all-special-charac)

Comment: @tripleee: we can set tags to have no highlighting, but I don't think we want to disable guessing altogether (which is the default for most tags). I don't recall what happens when you use, say, `[regex] [python]` if `regex` had highlighting set to `none`, but if that Just Works (code blocks default to being marked up as Python) then perhaps we should set `regex` to `none` by default.

Comment: @tripleee [Current maintainer of Highlight.js here] I've made the suggestion elsewhere that really short snippets should be defaulted to `none` (or use a heuristic) because guessing with so little data isn't going to produce great results.

Comment: I went looking for it so I could upvote it, but I guess it's just the last paragraph in a broader discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355496/169312)?

Comment: @tripleee see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/stop-guessing-auto-detecting-a-language-when-you-know-it-will-be-incorrect

Comment: Yeh, I found (and upvoted) that too, but it doesn't specifically discuss the case of short snippets.