# The code editor is italicizing some code blocks

Tags: bug, code-formatting

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64916848/2):

[image: Italicized code block]

I think it might have something to do with the arrow notation, since the italicized text didn't appear until I put that in.

Comment: Hmm, removing the Java tag solved the problem.  Still... ?

Comment: It was tagged with `c` and `java`, and due to the [improper auto-detection logic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401573/what-should-we-expect-from-syntax-highlighting-auto-detection/401660#401660), no language hints were sent to the highlighter, and it saw a few `*`s, so decided to format it as Markdown. Removing the Java tag fixes it because (see the link in the comment) when 2 or more tags associated with diff languages are on a question, the highlighter is called with no hint at all. Yeah, I'd [consider it a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354793)

Comment: Rather than removing the second tag, you can also explicitly mark the code block with the language it's using (though it looks like removing the tag was appropriate in this case anyway).

Comment: ^^^ Always defining the language on your code blocks would do away with this problem altogether.

Comment: Never had to do that before.

Comment: Ah, Robert, you expected the system to get *smarter*. Where do you get crazy ideas like that?

Comment: I sort of feel like italicization should not occur at all in code blocks.

Comment: [You're reading my mail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402864/code-block-is-rendered-incorrectly-partially-in-italic-after-underscore?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment807966_402864).