# There is italic in the code blocks (bug)

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

First time today I see some italic in a block code, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72997859/1):

> ```force-default
> from sympy import *
> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import *
> from sympy.abc import x,y,z,w,a,b,c,d
> eq = x*y + 1#parse_expr('((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2))^2*((x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2+296*(x^2+y^2)-4*(9*z^2+16*w^2)) -16*(x^2+y^2)*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2*(37*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^2-1369*(x^2+y^2)-7*(225*z^2+448*w^2)) -16*sqrt(3)/9*(x^3-3*x*y^2)*(110*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)^3 -148*(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+145/3)*(110*x^2+110*y^2-297*z^2+480*w^2)) -64*(x^2+y^2)*(3*(729*z^4+4096*w^4)+168*(x^2+y^2)*(15*z^2-22*w^2)) +64*(12100/27*(x^3-3*x*y^2)^2 -7056*(3*x^2*y-y^3)^2) -592240896*z^2*w^2', transformations=T[:])
> reps = {x: a*x - b*y - c*z - d*w,y:a*y + b*x + c*w - d*z,z:a*z - b*w + c*x + d*y,w:a*w + b*z - c*y + d*x}
> eq = eq.xreplace(reps)
> c = {}
> for i in Add.make_args(eq):
>     f = i.xreplace(reps).expand()
>     for s in Add.make_args(f):
>         co, mo = s.as_coeff_mul(x,y,z,w)
>         c.setdefault(Mul._from_args(mo), []).append(co)
>
> for k in c:
>     print(k,Add(*c[k])))
> ```

[image]

I just wanted to spot this bug.

Comment: Similar to [Code block containing asterisks displaying in italics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401610/code-block-containing-asterisks-displaying-in-italics). The Markdown syntax highlighting is used. Don't ask me why...

Comment: It doesn't show up in the revision history, either.  Check the revision history for this post as well: same thing happens. Weird.

Comment: The question has both a [tag:python] and [tag:r] tag so the syntax-highlighting is defaulted. Highlight.js decided it was markdown which is why it was highlighted the way it was. AFAICT Syntax-highlighting is never available in the revision history @RyanM

Comment: Related: [Stop guessing/auto-detecting a language when you KNOW it will be incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852/1099857)